# I need to find all files except one or two files in Ansible

Tags: windows, ansible

I need to find all files except few files. Actually I need to delete them after this.

I used the `win_find` module and exclude option. But it doesn't exclude it.

My code is as below.

```
  vars:
   exclude_files: dontdeletethis.txt
  tasks:
  - name: Find files
    win_find:
     paths: C:\temp\Test\fol1
     excludes: 'dontdeletethis.txt'
    register: log_files
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting simply an error out of this ? `excludes` is **not** listed in the [`win_find` module parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_find_module.html). It is a parameter for the [`find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) meant for *nix targets. There seems to be a `pattern` param however that might help you.

Comment: Yeah sure, i didn't get any error. when I did debug, it printed all files including the file mentioned to be excluded. I will find all files and then exclude it during deletion. hope that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me

```
---
  - name: Find log files to delete
    win_find:
     paths: C:\temp\Test\fol1
    register: log_files

  - name: Delete
    win_file:
     path: "{{item.path}}"
     state: absent
    when: 'dontdeletethis.txt not in item.path' 
    with_items: "{{log_files.files}}"
```